# Javascript eval onload in the correct scope

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run the javascript in the onload attribute of some image elements even when they fail to be retrieved or when they time out. Meaning `<img src="unretrievable" onload="alert(this.src);">` that would not be able to be retrieved but i want to run the code and give a message "unretrievable".

By contrast this `<img src="http://i657.photobucket.com/albums/uu296/cricketpet/Pussies/weird-cat-found.jpg" onload="alert(this.src);">` runs because the image is retrieved.

The problem with just evaluating the code with `eval` is that the variable `this` is not set, would a simple append to the beginning of the code of this snippet "`var this=element;`" and then an evaluation of the whole thing be acceptable?

Element on the above query is the image element

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? (Anyhow, using `eval` is almost always the wrong approach for anything.)

Comment: @Guffa Trying to run the code in the onload attribute.

Comment: You can add the `onerror` attribute to execute code when loading fails: `<img src="/path/to/my/image.jpg" onload="alert(this.src);" onerror="alert('error on ' + this.src)">`.

Comment: @Evan: What you say that you want to accomplish doesn't make sense. If you just want an alert to be executed, then just put the alert in a script tag, putting it in an onload event serves no purpose at all. So, what is it that you are relly trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Guffa That was just a simplification, the javascript tends to be dependent on the attributes of the element that made the request.

Comment: @MartinErnst thats a good idea, thnx :)

Comment: @Evan: I'm trying to find out what it is that you are actually trying to do. I can easily solve your simplification (i.e. `<script>alert('unretrievable');</script>`), but that will hardly be any useful for your real situation.